# Incorporating Ruby into jqPlot

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jqplot

#### Context :

I'm trying to create a pie chart using jqPlot, gathering data from a Rails database.

My problem occurs because jqplot doesn't understand the strings generated from event.name. If I manually insert a couple of strings, without going through Rails, it works fine.nI believe it has something to do with escaping characters it shouldn't be.

The error I get from Firebug shows `events = [[&quot;Title&quot;, 1234566]]`. Thus jqplot tries to create this chart with `&quot;Title&quot;` as a key. It doesn't like that.

I've tried using html_safe, to no avail.

---

#### Code :

```
<% things = [] %>
  <% @topEvents.each do |event| %>
<% things << [event.name, event.total] %>
<% end %>

$.jqplot('topEvents', [ <%= things %> ], {
    seriesDefaults : {
        renderer : jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions : {
            showDataLabels: true
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### Environment :

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.6
- SQLite3 3.6.20
- jquery-rails 2.0.2 (RubyGem)
- JQuery 1.7.2
- jqplot 1.0.0_r1012.

Comment: @Linuxios It's supposed to be ["Name_of_event", event_count], as String and integer, respectively.

Comment: @Linuxios I hadn't realized that SO read my html and changed my post...Firebug shows that jqPlot is trying to use `&quot;` within the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future googlers...

Although `"string"`  and `'string'` may be equivalent once they are declared in Ruby, this fact is irrelevant when it comes to javascript. Within a  `<script>` tag, ruby strings will show up as being double quoted. If you want single quotes, you're going to have to import the string as something other than a string, and then manually add the quotes later.

Javascript will understand `'<%= event.total %>'` just fine. It will use Rails to print out the total, and then the script will append single quotes to either side.

Hope this helps anyone!